# Allow a slice of any type into as argument

Tags: struct, go, types, arguments, slice

I am new to Go (coming from python) and I am having a bit of a hard time here. I am trying to allow any type of slice into my struct/func and it just contains a count of the length of that slice.

```
import "go/types"

type Response struct {
    Count int `json:"count"`
    Results []types.Struct `json:"results`
}

func NewResponse(results []types.Struct) (r *Response) {
    r.Count = len(results)
    r.Results = results
    return
}
```

Comment: What about using `json.RawMessage` as the type for each result, since you don't seem to know the JSON structure of the results up front. E.g. http://play.golang.org/p/jEx4UgBnLP.

Comment: Package go/types cannot be used for stuff like this. Redesign your solution: All these ideas of "any type" do not work very well in Go. Redesign. That works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `interface{}` as any type.

```
type Response struct {
  Count int `json:"count"`
  Results []interface{} `json:"results`
}
```

**UPDATE**

`len(rsp.results)` should work.
http://play.golang.org/p/RA2zVzWl2q

Comment: Cannot seem to call `len(results)` if it is an interface.

Comment: @electrometro: You can use reflection to get the length.

Answer (score 0):

Arbitrary types are totally legit in Go. In your case, it might be appropriate to use `[]interface{}` as the type of `Results`. When ever the types need to be known, use **type switch**.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Response struct {
    Count   int           `json:"count"`
    Results []interface{} `json:"results`
}

func NewResponse(results []interface{}) (r *Response) {
    r.Count = len(results)
    r.Results = results
    return
}

func AssertResultType(results []interface{}) {

    for _, v := range results {
        switch v := v.(type) {
        default:
            fmt.Printf("unexpected type %T\n", v) //t has unexpected type
        case bool:
            fmt.Printf("boolean %t\n", v) // t has type bool
        case int:
            fmt.Printf("integer %d\n", v) // t has type int
        case string:
            fmt.Printf("string %q\n", v) // t has type string
        }
    }

}

func main() {

    args := []interface{}{1, "hello", true, "foo", 21}    

    r := NewResponse(args)

    AssertResultType(r.Results)
}
```

In case of JSON, `*json.RawMessage` can be marshaled to type `[]byte`

```
type Response struct {
    Count   int              `json:"count"`
    Results *json.RawMessage `json:"results`
}
```